# Passing integer array as command line argument to powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell script:

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int[]]$Ports
)

Write-Host $Ports.count

foreach($port in $Ports) {
 Write-Host `n$port
}
```

When I run the script with `$ powershell -File ./test1.ps1 -Ports 1,2,3,4` it works (but not as expected):

```
1

1234
```

When I try to use larger numbers, `$ powershell -File .\test.ps1 -Ports 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12`, the script breaks entirely:

```
test.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Ports'. Cannot convert value "1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12" to type "System.Int32[]". Error: "Cannot convert value "1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input
string was not in a correct format.""
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [test.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,test.ps1
```

It seems like powershell is trying to process any numbers passed via the `Ports` param as a single number, though I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to get past it.

Comment: This is likely due to parsing by whatever is parsing your `powershell` command line. If you run your script (or function) from the PowerShell prompt itself, it should work as expected.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `-file` doesn't like argument arrays. `-command` works better. Does `powershell -Command "& .\test.ps1 -Ports 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12" ` work the way you want?

Comment: Seems to be runnning PoSh V 6.0.0beta on Linux/OSX @BenHs tip is working there fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that a parameter passed through `powershell.exe -File` is a `[string]`.

So for your first example,

```
powershell -File ./test1.ps1 -Ports 1,2,3,4
```

`$Ports` is passed as `[string]'1,2,3,4'` which then attempts to get cast to `[int[]]`. You can see what happens with:

```
[int[]]'1,2,3,4'
1234
```

Knowing that it will be an just a regular `[int32]` with the comma's removed means that casting `1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12` will be too large for `[int32]` which causes your error.

```
[int[]]'123456101112'
```

> Cannot convert value "123456101112" to type "System.Int32[]". Error: "Cannot convert value "123456101112" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too
>   large or too small for an Int32.""

---

To continue using `-file` you could parse the string yourself by splitting on commas.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Ports
)

$PortIntArray = [int[]]($Ports -split ',')

$PortIntArray.count    

foreach ($port in $PortIntArray ) {
    Write-Host `n$port
}
```

But luckily that is unnecessary because there is also `powershell.exe -command`.  You can call the script and use the PowerShell engine to parse the arguments. This would correctly see the `Port` parameter as an array.

```
powershell -Command "& .\test.ps1 -Ports 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12"
```