# Calling powershell script with C# - passing in string array as argument in powershell

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing C# code to execute a powershell script.
The powershell script has two arguments:

1. subscriptionId of type string
2. resourceGroupNames of type string[]

Problem:

1. When running the C# program, the resourceGroupNames that is passed a is not being read by the powershell script.
2. Additionally, when running the C# program, powershell prompts me a message "Do you want to run this script?" Is there anyway to suppress this alert and have the powershell script to run automatically?

Here is my code:
Note that chefRepo is the path of the powershell script.

```
public void DoDeploymentRTM(string chefRepo, string subscriptionId, string[] resourceGroupNames)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"& '{0}\AzurePowerShellScripts\azureVMStatusFetch.ps1' -subscriptionId {1} -resourceGroupNames {2}", chefRepo, subscriptionId, resourceGroupNames);
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at what is in startInfo.Arguments and you will see the problem.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: You need full path of powershell.exe.  The shell process class has no environmental properties like PATH.  So unless the pwershell.exe is in the same folder as the c# executable, otherwise, the full path name is needed.

Comment: @DanCode You seem to expect that string.Format("... {2}", ... resourceGroupNames) writes the array in a form Powershell recognizes as string array. This is not the case.

Comment: @KlausGütter, what can I do to make powershell recognize it as a string array?

Comment: I recommend that you first test the command line from a command prompt and then use this as guideline to formulate the string.Format. Maybe something like "(" + string.Join(",", resourceGroupNames.Select(n => "\"" + n + "\"") + ")" instead of just resourceGroupNames will work, but I did not test it.

Comment: For 2. use “-ExecutionPolicy Bypass” as an additional parameter. For 1. I’d use Process Explorer to see how the powershell.exe process gets invoked (parameter-wise), then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but, there is a more controllable way of executing powershell through C# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 1):

For passing an array as powershell argument you need to separate it's values by commas i.e. for integers you would pass e.g `1,2,3`.
For string you need additional quotation marks (in case some items contain space) e.g.`'first string','second string','third'`.
In C# you would do this by

```
string.Join(',', resourceGroupNames.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"))
```

In order to make this approach work when calling by `ProcessStartInfo` you need to use powershell option `-Command` so that the array would be parsed correctly (see more details in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466376/passing-integer-array-as-command-line-argument-to-powershell-script)).

Concerning your second problem use powershell commandline option `-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted`

Finally you just need to change your `Arguments` like this:

```
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -Command &\"'{0}\\AzurePowerShellScripts\\azureVMStatusFetch.ps1' - subscriptionId {1} -resourceGroupNames {2}\"", chefRepo, subscriptionId, string.Join(',', resourceGroupNames.Select(x => "'" + x + "'")));
```

or easier (for C# 7.0 or higher)

```
startInfo.Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -Command &\"'{chefRepo}\\AzurePowerShellScripts\\azureVMStatusFetch.ps1' - subscriptionId {subscriptionId} -resourceGroupNames {string.Join(',', resourceGroupNames.Select(x => $"'{x}'"))}\"";
```